# c# How to manipulate image array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have 17 different images that are being shuffled and then loaded in an Image array `Deck` from a string array `ImgLocation`. After this i'm adding the images to a picturebox array `Holder`.

So I want to know how can I have for example image with name "3.png" at position `Deck[0]`. I tried to use bitmap but this is not working the way it should because it might create a duplicate and I don't want this so. Is there a way to do this ?

```
   for (i = ImgLocation.Length; i > 0; i--)
   {
       int j = r.Next(i);
       var k = ImgLocation[j];
       ImgLocation[j] = ImgLocation[i - 1];
       ImgLocation[i - 1] = k;
   }
 for (i = 0; i < 17; i++)
 {
   Deck[i] = Image.FromFile(ImgLocation[i]);

   Bitmap card1 = new Bitmap("Assets\\Cards\\3.png");
   Bitmap card2 = new Bitmap("Assets\\Cards\\11.png");
   Bitmap card3 = new Bitmap("Assets\\Cards\\15.png");
   Bitmap card4 = new Bitmap("Assets\\Cards\\27.png");
   Bitmap card5 = new Bitmap("Assets\\Cards\\33.png");

   Holder[12].Image = card1;
   Holder[13].Image = card2;
   Holder[14].Image = card3;
   Holder[15].Image = card4;
   Holder[16].Image = card5;
}
```

Comment: I've read your question ten times and still I don't know what your problem is nor what you want

Comment: i want to get specific image at specific index of my picturebox array "Holder" i get the image location from the string array ImgLocation

Comment: Is this your actual code? Are you loading 5 bitmaps from the disk in a loop 17 times (85 Bitmap creation) ?

Comment: there's some more code i removed because it's off topic and no it's not looping 17 times

Comment: What about `Queue`? you can dequeue it and no duplicate image will be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this.  Sort the deck not the images.

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<card> deck = new List<card>();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
       public class card
    {
           string suit { get; set; }
           int rank { get; set; }
           Bitmap image { get; set; }
    }
​
```